# One fragment show on top of the previous fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have two **fragments**:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
   ...
}

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment{
   ...
}
```

My app firstly show the `FirstFragment` , by pressing a **button** on the `FirstFagment`, the `SecondFragment` is showing. That's when button on `FirstFragment` is pressed, the following code will run:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, firstFragment, secondFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

What I would like to have is that, when show the `SecondFragment`, I can **still see** the `FirstFragment` below it( `FirstFragment` is Overlayed by `SecondFragment`), so, I guess I need to have **transparent background** for my `SecondFragment`.

I set the `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in my `SecondFragment` layout file, but it is not transparent, why? How to achieve my requirement?

Comment: share your fragment layout of second fragment